# Conversion for string based enums Typescript 2.4+

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a string based enum (supported in TypeScript 2.4+). What is the best way to convert a string to the corresponding enum value (if it exists?). If it doesn't exist, defaulting to a value is fine.

```
export enum Theory {
  RLJ = 'r + l = j',
  WinterIsComing = 'winter is coming',
  TyrionIsAarysSon = 'i buy it',
  YoungGriffIsReal = 'doubtfull'
}
```

I started with the following, which of course wouldn't work.

```
function getTheory(theoryString: string): Theory {
  let theory: Theory = Theory.RLJ;
  if (theoryString in Theory) {
    theory = theoryString as Theory;
  }

  return theory;
}
```

An approach that might work would be to create a map of enum values to name, and do a reverse lookup, but it seems that shouldn't be necessary (or that TypeScript has a better built in approach).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achieve what you want to. The best I can give you is something like this:

```
function isTheSameTheory(theoryString: string, t: Theory) {
  return theoryString === t;
}
```

Or this (which is unsafe):

```
function toTheory(theoryString: string) {
  return theoryString as Theory;
}
```